# ChatBot return bug

Tags: java, chatbot

I'm working on a Chat Bot project, and I'm almost done, other than the fact that whenever I enter an input, it returns multiple outputs depending on the length of the input X.

Here is the source code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ChatBot
{
public static String getResponse(String value)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String X = longestWord(value);
    if (value.contains("you"))
    {
        return "I'm not important. Let's talk about you instead.";
    }
    else if (X.length() <= 3)
    {
        return "Maybe we should move on. Is there anything else you would like to talk about?";
    }
    else if (X.length() == 4)
    {
        return "Tell me more about " + X;
    }

    else if (X.length() == 5)
    {
        return "Why do you think " + X + " is important?";
    }

    return "Now we are getting somewhere. How does " + X + " affect you the most?";
}

private static String longestWord(String value){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (value);
    String longest = new String();
    "".equals(longest);

    while (input.hasNext())
    {
        String temp = input.next();
        if(temp.length() > longest.length())
        {
            longest = temp;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

}

This is for testing the Chat Bot:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {
    public static void main (String [ ] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    ChatBot e = new ChatBot();
    String prompt = "What would you like to talk about?";
    System.out.println(prompt);
    String userInput;
    userInput = input.next();
    while (!userInput.equals("Goodbye"))
    {
        System.out.println(e.getResponse(userInput));
        userInput = input.next();
    }

}
}

I am also trying to modify the Bot so it counts the number of times it has responded; and also modify it so it randomly returns a random response depending on the length of the input. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank You!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [Scanner.next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method which only returns the next word in the string. So if you input a string with multiple words, your bot will respond to each of them.

You can use [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to get the entire input string, instead of only 1 word.

---

To count the number of times your bot has responded, you can create a field in the bot class:

```
private int responseCount = 0;
```

Then if you change yout `getResponse` method from a static method to an instance method, you can update this value from this method:

```
public String getResponse(String value)
{
    String X = longestWord(value);  //Your longestWord should also not be static.
    this.responseCount++;        

    if (value.contains("you"))
    {
        ...
```

Comment: To be more precise: its not reading the next word, its just splitting by default on whitespaces. Therefore if the user inputs "bla test" it returns two seperated strings.

Comment: What if I just wanted to get the bot to reply in such a way:     What would you like to talk about?
how are you?
I'm not important. Let's talk about you instead.
I like Java programming Now we are getting somewhere.                 How does programming affect you the most?
bugs make me sad                                                 Tell me more about bugs.
they mean the code is not right

Comment: @user3077721 If you change `input.next()` to `input.nextLine()` in the main method, is that not what happens?

Comment: Never mind, I'd changed the .next() to .nextLine() elsewhere in the code, it's responding the way it should. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Regarding counting the responses, just modify your main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
public static void main (String [ ] args)
{
   int numberOfResponses = 1;
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
   ChatBot e = new ChatBot();
   String prompt = "What would you like to talk about?";
   System.out.println(prompt);
   String userInput;
   userInput = input.next();
   while (!userInput.equals("Goodbye"))
   {
      System.out.println(e.getResponse(userInput));
      userInput = input.nextLine();
      numberOfResponses++;
   }
   input.close();
   System.out.println(numberOfResponses);
}
}
```

If I have the time I will edit my post in a few minutes to check your problem regarding the double appearences of a response. You also forgot to close the Scanner.

EDIT: It actually happens because scanner has as a default the delimiter set to be on whitespace. so if you input a text with a whitespace, the while loop runs twice for one user input. Just use the nextLine() command.

Why is this code:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
```

In your getResponse method? Its not used at all. Take a closer look at your methods as they are holding some strange code.

Comment: What do you mean by strange?

Comment: Sry Im just not having the time to correct every aspect :) e.g. you have this code: `"".equals(longest);` which actually returns a boolean but is never used. Just like the scanner object which got not used and the close() statements for the scanner instances are also missing